# Galvanized Steel Heat Exchangers

Tags: thermodynamics

What are the advantages and disadvantages of galvanized steel heat exchanger? I am generating flue gases through pyrolysis process. Can I pass the flue gases through galvanized steel heat exchanger to heat water?

Comment: What gases are present in your pyrolysis gas, will there be condensation in the heat exchanger? With galvanized components be especially wary of any nitrogen compounds. Pyrolysis gas is a wide range of mixtures, ultimately you need to provide us the relevant species in your gas.

Comment: What are you pyrolyzing?  Wood?  Garbage?

Answer (score 5):

I presume you mean galvanized steel. Galvanizing would be a waste of time for flue gas. Carbonic acid ( CO2 + water) would dissolve/corrode the zinc. Sulfurous acid could be present causing even faster corrosion. Generally flue gases are a challenge for corrosion control.